# BufferedReader readLine() method taking so much time

Tags: java, process, bufferedreader

I am taking InputStream from a Process and reading it through BufferedReader. In while loop although, the br is having just one line, it is taking almost 1 minute. I checked this by printing before and after as shown in below code.

```
String[] sendCommand = { "/bin/bash", "/Users/apple/Downloads/yowsup-e56f2d28f38c7961a2ccf7df588462f1c9588edf/sendmessage.sh"};
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuilder.directory(new File("/Users/apple/Downloads/yowsup-e56f2d28f38c7961a2ccf7df588462f1c9588edf"));
processBuilder.environment().put("PYTHONPATH", "/Users/apple/Downloads/yowsup-e56f2d28f38c7961a2ccf7df588462f1c9588edf");
processBuilder.command(sendCommand);

Process process = processBuilder.start();
process.waitFor();  
InputStream stream = process.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
String temp = null;
System.out.println("before");
long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) 
{
    str = temp;
}
long end_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
long time_taken = end_time-start_time;
System.out.println("after");
System.out.println("Time taken in while loop: "+time_taken/1000);
```

The result was:

```
before
after
Time taken in while loop: 67
```

I want to improve the time taken as 1 minute is very slow. What are the possible options? Is it dependent on what Process I am using? Please help me.

Comment: Well what's the process doing? I very much suspect that this is due to the actions of the process rather than `BufferedReader`. What happens if you run the process from the command line or shell and watch it? You should also add some indication that it really *is* just reading one line - note that your loop won't finish until the process itself has completed, as that's when the stream will close and `readLine()` will return null.

Comment: My process is running a bash script before this. But how come while loop is taking time?

Comment: @DarshilBabel How long does the process take to finish?

Comment: Because the process is taking time, presumably. Again: what happens if you run it from the shell? I suspect you find it takes just over a minute to complete...

Comment: @Jon Skeet when i an running the process from shell, it is not taking 1 minute time. So can you tell me what to do if i want similar results in java.

Comment: When you run the process manually do you need to type anything? Does it print anything to stderr/System.err?

Comment: Well how long *does* it take? And did you add the diagnostics I suggested to check how many lines it's actually reading? Basically, without knowing more about what it's doing, it's pretty much impossible for us to help you...

Comment: @immibis No i do not need to type anything

Comment: @JonSkeet I added that part and it turns out it is reading 6 lines actually out of which I want only last line. I also edited my code portion, so that you can see what I am calling?

Comment: Well we can tell that you're calling `sendmessage.sh`, but we've no idea what that is. So, how many lines does it produce when you run it locally? Have you observed *when* the lines are read? I suggest you add logging in the loop, including a timestamp...

Comment: @JonSkeet when i am running it locally, first time it prints 4 lines and after that every time the lines increase by 1.

Comment: Right, so is it correct for it to read 6 lines in the Java code? At this point to be honest I think you need to go away and look at exactly what's going on, with timestamps, examining every line of output to check whether it's expected - and then come back and add a *lot* more information to your question if there's still anything to answer. It sounds like it's got everything to do with the process you're running and nothing to do with BufferedReader.

Comment: I just deleted the while loop code and read just the first line and it also takes around 1 minute.I am not sure but the problem is process throws the output to the terminal instantly but reading it is taking time.

Comment: What happen if you print out any line you read? Can you spot a delay at a specific stage?

Answer (score 2):

It's not the reading, it's the writing. `BufferedReader` can't go any faster than the output is produced. If there's nothing to read, it blocks. You're looking at the wrong end.

NB Your loop is basically pointless, or at best very odd. You're reading every line the process ever produces and throwing away all but the last line. Surely you should do something with every line?

Comment: Well I actually want only the last line from BufferedReader. I didn't know how to read just the last line.

Comment: @NwDx did you actually read the question? It's another process's stdout.

Comment: @DarshilBabel Well you *are* reading the last line, and the only way you can get it correctly is by reading to end of stream, and the only way to get end of stream is by blocking in `readLine()` until the process closes its `stdout,` or exits, so no improvement is possible.